# How to override product review list.phtml file?

Tags: magento2

I tried,
**app/design/frontend/Test/abc/Magento_Review/layout/review_product_list.xml**

```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="page.bottom.container">
    <referenceBlock name="product.info.product_additional_data">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Review::product/view/list.phtml</argument>
        </action>
    </referenceBlock>
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
 </page>
```

**app/design/frontend/Test/abc/Magento_Review/templates/product/view/list.phtml**

```
<?php
    $_items = $block->getReviewsCollection()->getItems();
    $format = $block->getDateFormat() ?: \IntlDateFormatter::SHORT;
?>
<?php if (count($_items)):?>
<div class="block review-list" id="customer-reviews">
<div class="block-title">
    <strong><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Customer Reviews new24234') ?></strong>
</div>
<div class="block-content">
    <div class="toolbar review-toolbar">
        <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('toolbar') ?>
    </div>
    <ol class="items review-items">
    <?php foreach ($_items as $_review):?>
        <li class="item review-item" itemscope itemprop="review" itemtype="http://schema.org/Review">
            <div class="review-title" itemprop="name"><?php echo $block->escapeHtml($_review->getTitle()) ?></div>
            <?php if (count($_review->getRatingVotes())): ?>
                <div class="review-ratings">
                <?php foreach ($_review->getRatingVotes() as $_vote): ?>
                <div class="rating-summary item" itemprop="reviewRating" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Rating">
                    <span class="label rating-label"><span><?php echo $block->escapeHtml($_vote->getRatingCode()) ?></span></span>
                    <div class="rating-result" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_vote->getPercent() ?>%">
                        <meta itemprop="worstRating" content = "1"/>
                        <meta itemprop="bestRating" content = "100"/>
                        <span style="width:<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_vote->getPercent() ?>%">
                            <span itemprop="ratingValue"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_vote->getPercent() ?>%</span>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
                </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <div class="review-content" itemprop="description">
                <?php echo nl2br($block->escapeHtml($_review->getDetail())) ?>
            </div>
            <div class="review-details">
                <p class="review-author">
                    <span class="review-details-label"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Review by')?></span>
                    <strong class="review-details-value" itemprop="author"><?php echo $block->escapeHtml($_review->getNickname()) ?></strong>
                </p>
                <p class="review-date">
                    <span class="review-details-label"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Posted on') ?></span>
                    <time class="review-details-value" itemprop="datePublished" datetime="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->formatDate($_review->getCreatedAt(), $format) ?>"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->formatDate($_review->getCreatedAt(), $format) ?></time>
                </p>
            </div>
        </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ol>
    <div class="toolbar review-toolbar">
        <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('toolbar') ?>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<?php endif;?>
```

Also created `register.php`, composer file and `theme.xml` in `Test/abc` folder and in backend theme is assigned.

But its not working.

Comment: Have you applied that theme in store ?

Comment: yes, I have applied the theme

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you place the file in the same location like you have done you **extend** the file, to completely override it you need to place it in the following directory:

```
<theme_dir>
  |__/<Namespace_Module>
    |__/layout
      |__/override
         |__/base
           |--<layout1>.xml
           |--<layout2>.xml
```

Or if you need to overwrite the file from a parent theme:

```
<theme_dir>
  |__/<Namespace_Module>
    |__/layout
      |__/override
         |__/theme
            |__/<Parent_Vendor>
               |__/<parent_theme>
                  |--<layout1>.xml
                  |--<layout2>.xml
```

### Your example

So if you are overriding `review_product_list.xml` from base (the module) you would create this file:

```
app/design/frontend/Test/abc/Magento_Review/layout/override/base/review_product_list.xml
```

And if you're overriding it from a parent theme:

```
app/design/frontend/Test/abc/Magento_Review/layout/override/theme/PARENT-VENDOR/PARENT-THEME/review_product_list.xml
```

If this doesn't work I think there is a bigger problem, such as a theme not being configured properly.

You can read more about overriding XML files in the dev docs [here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/layout-override.html).